# Angular: Detecting change in DOM using observables

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to read the changes in DOM of my angular component.

I am using observables to retrieve that change into a typescript variable (not sure whether thats the correct way to go). Here is how I have implemented it :

#### app.component.html

```
<input type="text" name="refl" [(ngModel)]="txt">
<app-test>
    <div class="t1">
        The text : {{txt}}
    </div>
</app-test>
```

#### test.component.html

```
<div #t><ng-content select=".t1"></ng-content></div>
Received Text : {{text}}
```

#### test.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './test.component.scss' ]
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild('t') private tq: ElementRef;
  private text: string = null;
  constructor () {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    new Observable(obs => {obs.next(this.tq.nativeElement.innerText);})
    .subscribe((dt: string) => { this.text = dt; });
  }
}
```

My understanding was that since I am using an observable to monitor change in the DOM, I would get reflected to the `{{text}}` in test.component.html.

But I am receiving nothing in that place.

Is this correct way of observing changes in DOM using angular.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does that supposed to do? You want to observer dom changes or simply output text?

Comment: @Antoniossss I simply want to retrieve that changes in DOM into a variable in typescript.

Comment: Use rxjs fromEvent: https://stackblitz.com/edit/domsubtree-changed

Comment: @Chellappan Thank you. That worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Probably question is bad but

> Angular: Detecting change in DOM using observables

You would have to use MutationObserver and push events from its callback to your observable object to react accordingly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you want to observe changes in the DOM and change the variable then you can use Subject.next()

Subject.next(): The subject next method is used to send messages to an observable which are then sent to all angular components that are subscribers of that observable.

Steps to achieve this

1) Make a service **MyService.Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
   private subject = new Subject<any>();

   UpdateText(message: string) {
      this.subject.next({ text: message });
   }

    clearText() {
      this.subject.next();
   }

    getText(): Observable<any> {
       return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

2) **app.component.html**

```
<input type="text" name="refl" [(ngModel)]="txt" (keyUp)="ChangeText()">
```

3) **app.component.ts**

```
import {myService} from './myservice.ts';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './test.component.scss' ]
 })
 export class AppComponent {
 txt: any;
 constructor (private myServiceObj: myService) {}

 ChangeText(){
   this.myServiceObj.UpdateText(txt);
 }
}
```

4) **test.component.html**

```
Received Text : {{text}}
```

5) **test.component.ts**

```
import {myService} from '../myservice.ts';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-test',
 templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './test.component.scss' ]
 })
export class TestComponent {

 private text: string = null;
 subscription: Subscription;

 constructor (private myServiceObj: myService) {
  this.subscription = this.myServiceObj.getText().subscribe(text => { 
  this.text = text; });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }  
}
```

enjoy coding :)